# Error on opening jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

Whenever I'm trying to open jmeter script then it's showing the following error. 
I already kept plugging in lib/etc folder but the error is still there. Please provide me the solution of this as soon as possible.

Comment: Add the error in log.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes file is corrupted, you should save your file before executing, JMeter save latest file, 
Try open latest file saved in [backups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#autosave) folder.

> Since JMeter 3.0, JMeter automatically saves up to ten backups of every saved jmx files.

Next version backup will be saved automatically on every run.

Answer (score -1):

Check all plugins are there. do you have a copy of the error message as they should help understand which plugin is the issue "missing".

Also if you have downgraded jmeter then you will also have an issue opening newer jmx files and they cant be opened by older versions.

So maybe a long shot but download the latest version and add your plugins in and try to open the jmx in that.